# Ho to Read files from a folder and save filename into a table using TSQl?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I have a folder and it has multiple files like abc1.txt,abc2.txt etc.
I want to store file names into a table using a TSQL.

Comment: I tried below code

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @files table (ID int IDENTITY, FileName varchar(100))
insert into @files execute xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\ /b'
select * from @files
```

Comment: i tried same, query is running successfully but on printing the contents of table, nothing is being displayed.?? Anything would u like to suggest.